# AWS EMR Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I m trying to run Mapper For Co-occurance on AWS EMR

Errorlog

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169)

System Log:

2019-04-18 00:34:29,518 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy (main): Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-1-199.us-east-2.compute.internal/172.31.1.199:8032
2019-04-18 00:34:29,741 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy (main): Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-1-199.us-east-2.compute.internal/172.31.1.199:8032
2019-04-18 00:34:30,046 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem (main): Opening 's3://abhavtwitterdataset/mr/mapper2.py' for reading
2019-04-18 00:34:30,240 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem (main): Opening 's3://abhavtwitterdataset/mr/reducer.py' for reading
2019-04-18 00:34:30,815 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader (main): Loaded native gpl library
2019-04-18 00:34:30,822 INFO com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec (main): Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 59c952a855a0301a4f9e1b2736510df04a640bd3]
2019-04-18 00:34:30,919 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat (main): Total input files to process : 4
2019-04-18 00:34:31,403 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter (main): number of splits:9
2019-04-18 00:34:31,559 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter (main): Submitting tokens for job: job_1555547086751_0002
2019-04-18 00:34:31,802 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl (main): Submitted application application_1555547086751_0002
2019-04-18 00:34:31,876 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): The url to track the job: http://ip-172-31-1-199.us-east-2.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1555547086751_0002/
2019-04-18 00:34:31,878 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Running job: job_1555547086751_0002
2019-04-18 00:34:41,076 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1555547086751_0002 running in uber mode : false
2019-04-18 00:34:41,078 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 0% reduce 0%
2019-04-18 00:34:59,350 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:01,388 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:09,627 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:11,646 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:12,657 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000004_0, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:13,667 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000005_0, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:15,682 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:15,683 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000006_0, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:30,760 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000005_1, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:30,761 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:34,782 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000003_1, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:39,816 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:40,824 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000004_1, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:41,829 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000002_1, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:45,851 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000006_1, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:35:45,853 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000005_2, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:36:00,941 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000002_2, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:36:00,944 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Task Id : attempt_1555547086751_0002_m_000006_2, Status : FAILED
2019-04-18 00:36:03,957 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main):  map 100% reduce 100%
2019-04-18 00:36:04,966 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Job job_1555547086751_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1555547086751_0002_m_000001
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

2019-04-18 00:36:05,073 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job (main): Counters: 17
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=19
        Killed map tasks=8
        Killed reduce tasks=3
        Launched map tasks=24
        Other local map tasks=17
        Data-local map tasks=7
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=20982096
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=437127
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=0
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=437127
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=671427072
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
2019-04-18 00:36:05,074 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob (main): Job not successful!

Code of Mapper For Co-occurance

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""mapper2.py"""

import sys
import nltk
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer

nltk.data.path.append("/tmp")
nltk.download('punkt', download_dir="/tmp")

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = re.sub(r'http\S+', '', line)
    # replace 't  by t
    line = re.sub(r"'t",'t',line)
stopwords = ['about', 'all', 'along', 'also', 'an', 'any', 'and', 'are', 'around', 'after', 'according', 'another',
            'already', 'because', 'been', 'being', 'but', 'become', 'can', 'could', 'called',
            'during', 'do', 'dont', 'does', 'doesn', 'did', 'didnt', 'etc', 'for', 'from', 'far',
            'get', 'going', 'had', 'has', 'have', 'he', 'her', 'here', 'him', 'his', 'how',
            'into', 'isnt', 'its', 'just', 'let', 'like', 'may', 'more', 'must', 'most', 
            'not', 'now', 'new', 'next', 'one', 'other', 'our', 'out', 'over', 'own', 'put', 'right',
            'say', 'said', 'should', 'she', 'since', 'some', 'still', 'such', 
            'take', 'that', 'than', 'the', 'their', 'them', 'then', 'there', 'these',
            'they', 'this', 'those', 'through', 'time', 'told', 'thing', 
            'use' ,'until', 'via', 'very', 'under',
            'was', 'way', 'were', 'what', 'which', 'when', 'where', 'who', 'why', 'will', 'with', 'would', 'wouldnt', 
            'yes', 'you', 'your']

lines = nltk.sent_tokenize(line)

for line in lines:
    #remove puntuation
    line = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',' ',line)
    # split the line into words
    words = line.split()

    for k in range(len(words) - 1):
        #stemming
        #l = ps.stem(words[k])
        l = words[k]
        l = l.lower()
        if l not in stopwords and len(l)>2 and  not (l.isdigit()):
            for j in words[k+1:]:
                r = j.lower()
                if r in stopwords or l == r or len(r)<=2 or r.isdigit():
                    continue
                key = l+"-"+r
                print("%s\t%s" % (key.lower(),1))
```